# Git hooks post-receive rake: not found

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, hook, githooks

Don't know why but rake tasks are not working on my git 'post-receive' hooks.

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/static_app --git-dir=/var/repo/static_app.git checkout -f
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
sudo service nginx restart
```

Here is server log I get when i `git push live`

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 777 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hooks/post-receive: 3: hooks/post-receive: rake: not found
remote: hooks/post-receive: 4: hooks/post-receive: rake: not found
remote: Restarting nginx: nginx.
To ssh://root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx/var/repo/static_app.git
   178b5cc..4c3d726  master -> master
```

How to fix this?

Comment: it seems that rake (https://github.com/ruby/rake) is not installed on the remote-machine. make sure that you can execute rake when using `/bin/sh` and your git-hook will work fine.

Comment: when i use rake task manually on remote server same tasks works fine. Doesn't that say that I have rake installed?

Comment: which shell are you using? i assume it is a bash. does it all work, if you use a /bin/sh?
if so, rake probably only is loaded for login-shells. you can find a nice guide about what files get loaded when here:  http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html.

also, if rake is part of your bundle, you should execute it in the correct directory. e.g. `cd /var/www/static_app && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: sorry but I don't know what is /bin/sh? How can I check this?

Comment: just log in to your remote-server and type /bin/sh. its another environment to execute your commands in. possibly this environment does not know rake. (while /bin/bash does). if so try to make the first line of your hook `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @pierrebeitz I tried using /bin/sh manually and it worked. But it doesn't work no matter what I use on post-receive.